# Center vertically inside rect pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm trying to center the text vertically inside a rect but it's always off by by a little bit.

The font used is the Helvetica and the font size is set to 12 and I'm setting a padding of 6 points above and below the letter and I'm setting the size of the rect as 24 points.

The code used to write the cells is below and the image shows the cell uncentered vertically.

[image: Uncentered cells]

```
public void drawCell(PDPageContentStream owningStream, float xOffset, float yOffset) throws IOException {
    float cellHeightSpacing = fontSize / 2;
    float height = yOffset  - fontSize - cellHeightSpacing;
    if (isContentLargerThanCell()) {
        if (maxLines < 2)
            return;

    } else {
        float x = xOffset+getAlignedX(" "+content+" ");
        drawContent(owningStream," "+content+" ",x,height);
    }
    drawCellBoundaries(owningStream, xOffset, yOffset - 2 * fontSize, 2 * fontSize);
}

private void drawCellBoundaries(PDPageContentStream owniContentStream, float X, float startHeight, float sizeHeight) throws IOException {
    owniContentStream.addRect(X, startHeight, width, sizeHeight);
owniContentStream.stroke()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have two issues to cope with:

- **For a given font size *fs*, hardly any letter actually has a height of *fs*, usually short sequences of letters don't either.**

  Your code assumes that it has to vertically center content of height *fs* but you use capital letters without any part beneath the base line, so their height is considerably less than *fs*.
- **The y coordinate you use for drawing text is the height of the base line, not the height of the bottom of all text.**

  E.g. look at this letter

  [image: g]

  If you draw this letter at some coordinates *x*,*y*, its descender will be drawn even **below** your *y* height while your code assumes for centering that the whole letter is located between *y* and *y* + *fs*.

---

The former problem most likely will have to remain. If you vertically center for the exact appearance of the letters, neighboring cells might have jumping base lines which will look worse than a certain degree of being off-center.

Your main problem is the latter one, and you can solve it by increasing the height of text drawing (or lowering the height of the boundary drawing) by *fs* times the absolute value of the maximum descent of the font.

You can retrieve the font descent from the font's font descriptor (`PDFontDescriptor.getDescent()`) or the font's bounding box (`PDFont.getBoundingBox()`)

Comment: That's kind of what I started to realize as I went a little bit "deeper" into the glyphs and their sizes. So I can just call the size of the rect by (2 * fontSize) - (fontSize * font.getFontDescriptor().getDescent()) correct? I did some testing and did notice that if I use around 80% of twice the height of the font it does look centered but that created a whole other issues. Anyway thank you very much mkl.

Comment: I probably would not resize the rectangle but merely move the text inside the rectangle

Comment: So rather than centering it at yOffset - fontSize - cellSpacing you'd do yOffset - (fontSize - fontSize * font.getFontDescriptor().getDescent()) - cellSpacing? Basically instead of saying to lower the fontSize you lower the height by the fontSize minus how much descent there is?

Comment: That would be my approach. When testing that, I'd propose using letter groups which both have a high ascender and a low descender, like "AjMg",

Comment: I see. If there are multiple lines in the cell (you can see from the code that's the next step of the implementation) I should do n * (fontSize - (fontSize * descent)) correct?

Comment: Probably `n * fontSize - fontSize * descent`.  But for a finalized opinion I'd have to see the code with support for multiple lines.

Comment: I see, I'll add that code later today or possibly tomorrow, would you be able to give an opinion on it then? (No rush, just to know that you'll will actually get a notification or something from stackoverflow)

Comment: @DMH You can make sure by also adding a comment here with **at mkl** like I added the **at DMH** up front here.

Comment: here is my code
Handling only 1 line of text for cells that are 1 line or larger in size
    float tempHeight = (height / 2) + (descriptor.font.getFontDescriptor().getDescent() * descriptor.fontSize / 1000);
    float heightToWrite = yOffset - height + tempHeight;

Comment: @DMH Can you put it into context? I.e. edit your question , adding an "Update" section in which you show your code with the changes applied?

Comment: @mkl the closest I've been of finding the center in height is this:
`y = yEnd + Math.abs(yStart - yEnd) / 2 - textHeight / 2 - font.getFontDescriptor().getDescent() * fontSize / 1000f;`
where
`textHeight = font.getFontDescriptor().getFontBoundingBox().getHeight() * fontSize / 1000f`. Is this what you mention or do you have a better approach?

Comment: @IvanRF I don't have a better approach in mind, especially if the effort is to remain acceptable. You might get an improved result if actually analyzing the font, but I doubt it's worth the trouble.